# Add HTTP_USER_AGENT to Django RequestFactory request?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-testing

Is there a way to add a user agent string to a RequestFactory request object?  I have the following test:

```
def test_homepage(self):
    request = self.factory.get(reverse('home'))
    response = views.home_page(request)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

The problem is that the home_page view calls a function that requires request.META["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].  As a result, the above test is raising a KeyError because it doesn't know what HTTP_USER_AGENT is.  Is there a way to add it to the RF's request object?  I know I can add it if I use Django's Client object but I'd prefer not to go this route as I want to eliminate all middleware involvement in my test.

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pass HTTP_USER_AGENT as keyword argument.

```
request = self.factory.get(reverse('home'), HTTP_USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/overview/#django.test.client.Client.get via https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.client.RequestFactory

Comment: As the documentation does show (and I've proven to myself via a second test), your suggestion works if one is using the test Client class.  However, you'll still get the KeyError I described if you're using a RequestFactory object.

Comment: @Robert, I tested myself. It works both for Client, RequestFactory.get.

Comment: @Robert, BTW, I used Django 1.5.1.

Comment: The view function that I used for test just print User Agent: `def home(request): return HttpResponse(request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])`

Comment: I believe you but my test is still failing.  Perhaps it's because of the way my code is written.  The first line in my views.home_page function is "type_of_device = detect_device(request)" and the first line in the detect_device function is "user_agent = request.META["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]".  Could it be that the HTTP_USER_AGENT we're passing to the home_page view isn't getting passed down into the detect_device function it's calling?

Comment: @Robert, How about setting HTTP_USER_AGENT before calling the view function? (Insert `request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'blah'`  line before `response = ...` line.)